# Rewriting Google Maps for AJAX

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want the user to press a button, where AJAX load will load Google Maps. I have several questions. First, where do I put the script API key. In the original file or the AJAX file? Second, I'm not sure what to write to load the google maps event initializer. Here is the code.

First File

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=false&libraries=drawing">
</script>

<div id="themapsection">

<input type="button" id="tour_dates" Value="Show Tour Dates" />

<script type="text/javascript" >

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tour_dates').click(function () {
  var theid = <?php echo $user_id; ?>;  
  $('#map_canvas').load(
  'ajax_map_tour_data.php', 
  {session_user_id: theid},
  function() {  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)})
;});});

</script>

</div>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

In the ajax file I have already created the function initialize. I decided to take this piece of code below from the ajax file and attach it to the original file but I know this isn't right. I just don't know where to go from here.

```
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the initialize function at the ajax load (success) event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tour_dates').click(function () {
    var theid = <?php echo $user_id; ?>;  
    $('#map_canvas').load(
      'ajax_map_tour_data.php', 
      {session_user_id: theid},
      initialize
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? Sorry, this is my first time playing with an ajax file containing javascript, let alone google maps api.

Comment: I rewrote what I assume to be the answer but still nothing was rendered in `#map_canvas`. Am I correct to believe that `(window, 'load',initialize)` is preventing the AJAX call from working?

Comment: Surely, Google map content isn't loaded that way? You need to be using statements like `map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, ...);` and `marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map:map, ...});`.

Comment: Well, I wrote that in the AJAX file. But do I need that in the original file instead?

Comment: this is intended to be included from the main file not the ajax file

Comment: Maybe then AJAX is not what I want.

Comment: The ajax request should be made with `$.ajax(...)`, not `.load()` and the requested script should return *data*, typically JSON-encoded. The ajax success handler should interpret the data and execute `google.maps...` statements to specify the map and its overlays.

Comment: What I wanted was to prevent the user from making a request to google maps when they load the page. Instead they would have to click on a button to see the map, helping me not go over the request limit set by google maps.

Comment: With that objective, then no you don't need AJAX. Instead, wrap all your map initialisation statements in a function which is called in response to the user clicking the button. eg. `$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#tour_dates').click(function() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], options);
  //other google.maps statements here
 });
});`